# Show that $f(\operatorname{int} A) = \operatorname{int}(f(A))$ when f is a homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology

> Show that $f(\operatorname{int} A) = \operatorname{int}(f(A))$ when f is a homeomorphism.

My trial is as follows. It seems to me that there is an error or it needs more detail. Any answer or comment is welcome.

> $f(\operatorname{int} A)\subset\operatorname{int}(f(A))$

Consider any $x\in int A\subset A\subset X$, then $\exists \, U \underset{open}\subset X$ such that $x\in U$ and $U\subset A$. So $$f(x)\in f(int A) \implies \exists f(U)\underset{open}\subset Y \text{ such that } f(x)\in f(U)\subset f(A)\subset int(f(A))$$

> $\operatorname{int}(f(A))\subset f(\operatorname{int} A)$

Suppose $f(x)\in int f(A)$, then
 $$ \exists f(U) \underset{open}\subset Y \text{ such that } f(x)\in f(U)\subset f(A)$$
 $\implies$ $x\in A$ and $\exists\, U\subset f^{-1}(f(U))\subset A \subset  X$.

Since $f(U)$ is open, $U\underset{open}\subset X$ such that $x\in U\subset A$. And then
 $$ x\in int A \implies f(x)\in f(int A)$$
 Hence, $f(int A) = intf(A)$

Comment: You essentially have the right idea. In the second part, just explain why $U$ is an open set, and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first part, the formulation could be improved, but the idea is correct. You take an open $U$ so that $x\in U\subseteq A$, and then it follows that $f(x)\in f(U)\subseteq f(A)$ and, as $f$ is an open map, $f(U)$ is open, so $f(x)$ is in the interior.

The second part contains some syntax errors, so I can't really say about that.
One way to show that is 
$$\text{int}(f(A))=f(f^{-1}(\text{int}(f(A))))⊆f(\text{int}(f^{-1}(f(A))))=f(\text{int}(A))$$ where for the last equality we use the injectivity, and for the inclusion we use the continuity of $f$.

Note that surjectivity isn't used, so the equality holds for all open embeddings.