# Prove that $ f^2(N) \subset Int f(N)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm trying to prove a theorem that implies that
for $f$ an homeomorphism and  $N$ is a compact subset of $X$ (a metric space). 
If $f(N) \subset Int(N)$ then  $f^{n+1} \subset Intf^{n}$, $Int$ is the interior of the set.
And is easy to prove that if $f^2(N) \subset Int f(N)$ then $f^{n+1}(N) \subset Int f^n(N)$
But I don't know how to prove that $f^2(N) \subset Int f(N)$.
I've tried to prove it like this:

Supose that it exists $y \in f^{2}(N) \not\subset Int(f(N)) \text{ with } y= f^2(x), x \in N$. Then as $f(N) \subset Int(N) \Longrightarrow \text{ and beacause } f \text{ is continous }, f^2(N) \subset f(Int N) \Longrightarrow y \in f(Int N)$\
$So $ y \in $f(Int N)$, then we can make $y=f(z)$ with $z \in Int N$. And $N$ is compact then is closed, so $y \in \overline{N}\backslash Int N = \partial N$ (The frontier of the set $N$)
Then it exists a sequence $a_n$ in $X\backslash f(N)$ that tends to $y=f(z)$ 
Finally we can take a sequence $f^{-1}(a_n) \not\in N$ that tends to $z$, so $z \not\in N (\longrightarrow \longleftarrow)$ because $z \in Int N \subset N$
But i'm not sure about the last part, so I would like to ask, if it is correct to say that "if $f^{-1}(a_n) \not\in N$ tends to $z$, then $z \not\in N$  "

Comment: yeah, that's easy to prove, but I want to prove the stronger one $f^2(N) \subset Int f(N)$

Comment: $f(\text{Int}(N)) = \text{Int}(f(N))$ https://math.stackexchange.com/a/757908/659499

Comment: Oh thanks, that helps a lot